# android google maps api v2 set route and fix moving

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, routes

I need draw route between multiple point (route) with red color. User moving with this route (i detect user location) and route change color to green.

I use android google api v2.

I crete route A-B-..-Z with map.addPolyline(rectLine) red color.

User moved by this route and i need mark him path with green color if user moved by route.

What i can use from api?

Comment: can you explain better because I dont know what you are asking

Comment: I need draw route between multiple point (route) with red color. User moving with this route (i detect user location) and route change color to green.

Answer (score 1):

Use [PolyLine.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline)

The route is usually drawn with PolyLine but you would only be able to make the segments separated by PolyLine vertices green.